# Specific database search

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to display single row from from different groups. 
I mean if I have for example table like:

```
id|name|groupID
1 |....|  1
2 |....|  1
3 |....|  1
4 |....|  2
5 |....|  2
6 |....|  3
7 |....|  4
8 |....|  4
9 |....|  4
```

it will display only one row from every groupID, one for groupID=1, one groupID=2 and so on.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: use group by `SELECT * FROM my table GROUP BY goupID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
  from tableName
  where id in (
    select max(id) from tableName group by groupID
  )
```

Comment: Dont do this, impossible to have 2 items in same group if he do this

Comment: He said "I'm looking for a way to display single row from from different groups"

Comment: HE dont say 'i want store unique groupId in my database'

Comment: Yeah this SQL work, and will return all last ID for each groupId

Answer (score 0):

[Group by doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) :

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Sql :

```
SELECT * FROM my table GROUP BY goupID
```

Return should be :

```
id|name|groupID
1 |....|  1
4 |....|  2
6 |....|  3
7 |....|  4
```

---

[Distinct doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) :

> In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

Sql :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(goupID) FROM my table
```

Return should be :

```
groupID
1
2
3
4
```

---

Hope that help you.

Comment: That wouldn't work as it's lacking an aggregate function, as stated in your above quote. You might add `MIN(id)`, but you'd still unable to use `*`.

Comment: In MySQL the query is valid and it runs but the values of columns that are neither in the `GROUP BY` clause, nor used with an aggregate function are not predictable. It can, as well, return 2, 5, 6 and 9 for `id`. However, the request is to get a single row from each group, it doesn't specify which one, so this query is good enough for this purpose.

Comment: @axiac Yeah maybe but i think he just need to list all groupId in this table and if sql return 2,5,6,7 its ok 'it will display only one row from every groupID'